# The basic statistics estimation for the tables of Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I know we could explicitly `ANALYZE` the table in Spark SQL so we could get some exact statistics.

However, is it possible that there exists some utilities in `Catalyst` which does not require explicitly scan the entire table but it could give me some rough statistics. I don't really care about the real size of a table, I only care about the relative size between tables. So I could use this info to decide which table is larger than others during query compilation.

There are two utilities in `Catalyst`:

`org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.statsEstimation.{BasicStatsPlanVisitor,SizeInBytesOnlyStatsPlanVisitor}`

But it looks like they both require explicitly scan the table.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, either the stats will be taken from metastore, which requires running `ANALYZE` in advance (scan over data) or the stats (only SizeInBytes actually) will be estimated using `InMemoryFileIndex` which does not require scanning over the data but using Hadoop api Spark gathers size of each file.

Which of these methods will be used depends on more settings. For example if the `SizeInBytes` is available in metastore and CBO (cost based optimization) is enabled by configuration setting

```
spark.cbo.enabled
```

, Spark will take it from metastore. If CBO is off (which is default value in Spark 2.4), Spark will use `InMemoryFileIndex`. If `SizeInBytes` is not available in metastore Spark can still use either `CatalogFileIndex` or `InMemoryFileIndex`. `CatalogFileIndex` will be used for example if your table is partitioned, more specifically if this is satisfied (taken directly from the Spark source code):

```
val useCatalogFileIndex = sparkSession.sqlContext.conf.manageFilesourcePartitions && catalogTable.isDefined && catalogTable.get.tracksPartitionsInCatalog && catalogTable.get.partitionColumnNames.nonEmpty
```

In this case if the stats are not in metastore, Spark will use `defaultSizeInBytes` from a configuration setting:

```
spark.sql.defaultSizeInBytes
```

which is by default `Long.MaxValue`, so the size will be overestimated to maximum value. I guess this is the worst scenario, the stats are not in metastore, but Spark is looking for them there using CatalogFileIndex, it does not find it and thus uses very large unrealistic value.